# Find the best solution for the different direction extension problom

Tags: oop

I hava an object which may extend in different directions, such as a fruit can be extended by type and color.

```
abstract class Fruit
{
   float GetPrice() { }
}

class Apple ： Fruit { }
class Banana ：Fruit { }
class RedApple : Apple { }
class BlueApple ：Apple { }
class RedBanana : Banana { }
class BlueBanana ：Banana { }
```

there will be too many subclasses and it's hard to reuse.
is there a better solution?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no information about responsibilities of classes, but probably decorator pattern is what you are looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't `redApple` be a subclass of `Apple` ?

Comment: Thank you, this is my mistake, redapple should be a subclass of apple.

Comment: That awkward feeling when I read the word `best` in a question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
abstract class Fruit
{
   float GetPrice() { }
}

class Apple ： Fruit { }
class Banana ：Fruit { }
class RedApple : Apple { }
class BlueApple ：Apple { }
class RedBanana : Banana { }
class BlueBanana ：Banana { }
```